# Get the current process port in Java

Tags: java, networking, process, runtime, port

In order to get the process number of my java application I am using:

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()
```

I also need to get the current port number the the process uses, but I can't seem to find how I can get it from the runtime.

Is there any way for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

A program doesn't use/open a port by default.
You (-> a program) need to query the OS to get a (free) port.
Thus there's no general way to query a running process for its' used port.
Maybe this tutorial will help you: https://www.baeldung.com/java-free-port